# get total data after of filter data with * ngIf

Tags: angular

basically I have an array with data.

```
aData=[
 {"name":"marge"},
 {"name":"homer"},
 {"name":"bart"},
 {"name":"homer"},
 {"name":"lisa"
]
```

I'm filtering where the name is equal to "homer".

```
<p>Total data is {{i}}</p>
<div *ngFor="let item of aData; let i=index">
  <span *ngIf="item.name='homer'"></span>
</div>
```

to show the total length of the elements filtered elsewhere.

```
 <p>Total data is {{i}}</p> //this result is blank
```

My data is dynamic, not always the result is 2 (in this case)

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if you want to do comparison of values, you should be using triple equals `===`. It should be `*ngIf="item.name==='homer'"`, and not `*ngIf="item.name='homer'"`.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of aData; let i=index">
  <span *ngIf="item.name==='homer'">{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Next, the solution provided by the other user is invalid, as [Angular no longer provide built in filter pipes.](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#built-in-pipes). Therefore, if you want to write your own custom pipe if you want to use the pipe solution.

My alternate solution to not using pipes is to handle the filtering within your component.ts. We will first define a property called count, which contains the filtered count of the number of elements with the name 'homer'.

```
count:number = 0; 

constructor() {
  this.count = this.aData.filter(data => data['name'] === 'homer').length;
}
```

And on your component.html, we use template interpolation to reflect the property value on your view.

```
<p>Total data is {{count}}</p>
<div *ngFor="let item of aData; let i=index">
  <span *ngIf="item.name==='homer'">{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Check out the full demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyqzlp?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.ts).

Answer (score -1):

I just write basic Angular search filter code snippet with `Total Items` and `Filtered Items` count. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

**TS**

```
aData=[
 {"name":"marge"},
 {"name":"homer"},
 {"name":"bart"},
 {"name":"homer"},
 {"name":"lisa"}
]
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
<p>Total data is {{aData.length}}</p>
<div *ngFor="let item of aData | filter:searchText; let i=index">
  <span *ngIf="item.name='homer'"></span>
</div>
<p>Total Filtered data is {{(aData | filter:searchText).length}}</p>
```

Comment: Angular neither provides nor recommends using filter pipe in template because of the performance issues.

Comment: @SachinGupta i don't know where you heard that **Angular neither provide or nor recommends using pipes**, but here is the Angular official Pipes documentation. https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: the comment is about the usage of `filter` pipes, not about the pipes in general

Comment: For more clarifications please share link where **Angular not recommend using pipes**. Thanks

Comment: Please read the full page at the link you shared, specifically the appendix: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe